# On angles between subspaces in infinite dimensional spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, soft-question

I just did an exersice which shows, atleast according to me that in general we dont know that we dont have parallell vectors in two closed subspaces if we only know that the intersection of the two closed subspaces is trivial and visa versa. I showed $\alpha (Y,Z) = 0$ and $Y \cap Z = \{0\}$ where $\alpha (Y,Z) = 0$ is given by $cos( \alpha (Y,Z)) =sup \{ \mid (y,z)\mid ; y \in Y z \in Z \mid\mid z \mid \mid = \mid \mid y \mid \mid =1 \}$ we are in some arbitrary Hilbert space of infinte dimension. Is my interpretation of this right?

Comment: most excellent misspelling of title.

Comment: @JamesS.Cook Fixed. Maybe thats where they hang out afterall :P

Comment: It seems probable that the afterlife and the spiritual involves infinite dimensions. I wonder, is "angel" used in a technical sense somewhere in math? I know ghosts are no joke in physics. They are necessary for probability to make sense in certain quantized field theories if I remember the story right...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. In finite dimensions , if $||z_n||=||y_n||=1$ and $(z_n,y_n)\ge 1-2^{-n}$ for $ n \in N$ then for some strictly increasing $f:N\to N$, the sequences $(z)_{f(n)}$ and $(y)_{f(n)}$ will converge in norm  to the same unit vector. This is because a finite-dimensional Banach space is locally compact.But in infinite dimensions, the sequences $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ might not have any convergent subsequences, and two  closed subspaces $Y,Z$ which intersect only at $0$  may still have  unit vectors $ y\in Y, z\in Z$ which are arbitrarily close to each other.